# Split on a value but keep value in the result array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a method that searches for items that match a query like C#'s Linq.

So for example:

```
myObj.query("name == 'Bob' and age >= 18");
```

So taking that I thought that the best place to start is to get each group, so first I am splitting on `and` and `or`. This seems to be giving me half of what I want.

So I am doing this:

```
Object.prototype.query = function(string){
    console.log(string.split(/(?=(and|or))/g));
};
```

The issue is, I am getting the wrong output in the console:

```
0: "name == 'Bob' "
1: "and"
2: "and age >= 18"
```

I am looking for something more like this (note 2, it no longer contains `and`):

```
0: "name == 'Bob'"
1: "and"
2: "age >= 18"
```

I think I am going in the right direction, I am just not that good with regex, so what should I do to split on the two values but keep them in the output?

Comment: Just a thought, this won't work if "and" or "or" are anywhere else in the string. `Randy` as a name would cause the string to split in the wrong place with your regex above.

Comment: true... maybe there is a better approach than regex?

Comment: Can you use `&&` or `||` in place of `and` and `or`?

Comment: yeah I can, I was thinking of accepting both but I could do that too.

Comment: maybe I will have to write a lexer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're using the positive lookahead modifier. You also need to make sure not to catch partial words, so I added a space delimiter. `/\s+(and|or)\s+/` as in

```
"name == 'Bob' and age >= 18 and ornate=='lando'".split(/\s+(and|or)\s+/)
```

will work, returning

```
["name == 'Bob'", "and", "age >= 18", "and", "ornate=='lando'"]
```

Checking for "and" inside strings gets a bit trickier, but with your current alternatives (strings or numbers) this would work `/\s+(and|or)\s+(?![\w\s]*')/`

```
"name == 'Bob' and age >= 18 and ornate='me and lando'".split(/\s+(and|or)\s+(?![\w\s]*')/)
```

returning

```
["name == 'Bob'", "and", "age >= 18", "and", "ornate='me and lando'"]
```

Comment: Works but if the quoted one is first or in the middle it doesn't pick up the closing apostrophe

Comment: My modified one didn't work at all so I removed it. I'm gonna let someone else take it for your updated request. Or just make it a new question since it's a new requirement, your original question has been answered.

Comment: Okay. I will keep it simple for now until I get what I want working.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It got hairy but I found it, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
Object.prototype.query = function(string){
    console.log(string.split(/\s+(and|or)\s+/g));
};

var myObj = {};
myObj.query("name == 'Bob' and age >= 18");
```

Produces

```
[ 'name == \'Bob\'', 'and', 'age >= 18' ]
```

Comment: what if query query looks like this: `companyName == 'Bob and Joe'`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Not sure why Jan removed console.log(string.split(/['\d]+\s+(and|or)\s+/)); - it seems to work.  May be it needed ['\d] only in beginning of regex

Comment: because it removed the last value such as `'` and `8` from `18`

Comment: Okay, I see.  Try this console.log(string.split(/['\d]+\s+(and|or)\s+/));  it will work